# Upload File on Multiple File Upload Control Simultaneously Using jQuery and ASP.Net Handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a form with multiple file upload control and a handler to upload file in chunk. This is working fine for upload a single file on an upload control at a time. But I want to upload file on multiple upload control simultaneously with chunk upload.Please suggest.

```html
$(inputUploadElem).fileupload({
    url: '../Handler.ashx?upload=start',
    maxChunkSize: 10000000,
    //  fileInput: $(this).prop("files"),
    sequentialUploads: true,

    dropZone: $(this),
    //singleFileUploads: false,
    //  limitMultiFileUploads: 1,


    add: function (e, data) {
        var uploadErrors = [];
        globalid = $(this).attr("id");
        var file = data.files[0];
        oldfname = file.name;
        var name = file.name;
        var fname = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
        var ext = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));

        var dt = new Date();

        var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = dt.getDate();

        
        var strTempImg = "_" + dt.getFullYear() + "_" + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + "_" + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day + "-" + dt.getHours() + dt.getMinutes() + dt.getSeconds();

        filename = fname + strTempImg + ext;
        globalid = $(this).attr('id');
        pathToUpload = $(this).attr('path');
        PathByControl = '';
        if (uploadErrors.length > 0) {
           
            alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));

        }
        else
            data.submit();

    },
    formData: function (data) {
        var arrFormData = [];
        arrFormData.push({ name: "file", value: filename });
        arrFormData.push({ name: "controlid", value: globalid });
        arrFormData.push({ name: "RootPath", value: pathToUpload });
        arrFormData.push({ name: "PathByControl", value: PathByControl });
        return arrFormData;
        
    },
    done: function (response, status) {
        PopulateData(globalid);
        $('.uploadprogress', "#UploadDiv_" + globalid.substring(globalid.indexOf('_') + 1, globalid.length)).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    },
    success: function (response, status) {
        if (!(response === undefined || response == null))
        {
            var repData = JSON.parse(response);
            //Sending conditional path for next chunk
            PathByControl = respData.PathByControl;
        }

    },
    error: function (error) {      
        $('.uploadprogress', "#UploadDiv_" + globalid.substring(globalid.indexOf('_') + 1, globalid.length)).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        alert("An error has occurred during processing your request.");
    },
    chunksend: function (e, data) {
        
    },
    progress: function (e, data) {
        // Track Progress
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        
        $('.uploadprogress', "#UploadDiv_" + globalid.substring(globalid.indexOf('_') + 1, globalid.length)).css('display', '');
        $('.uploadprogress', "#UploadDiv_" + globalid.substring(globalid.indexOf('_') + 1, globalid.length)).css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.uploadprogress', "#UploadDiv_" + globalid.substring(globalid.indexOf('_') + 1, globalid.length)).css('width', progress + '%');
        
    }
});
```

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection headers = context.Request.Headers;

    string rootPath = string.Empty,nodifiedFileName=String.Empty,controlId=String.Empty,pathByControl=String.Empty;
    if (context.Request.Form.Count >0 )
    {
        nodifiedFileName = context.Request.Form["file"];
        controlId = context.Request.Form["controlid"];
        rootPath = context.Request.Form["RootPath"];
        pathByControl = context.Request.Form["PathByControl"];
    }


    HttpRequest Request = context.Request;

    long chunks = 0;
    long chunk = 0;
    var Range = headers["Content-Range"];
    string startPosition = String.Empty;
    if (Range != null)
    {
        string[] arr = Range.ToString().Split('/');
        chunks = Convert.ToInt64(arr[1]) - 1;
        chunk = Convert.ToInt64(arr[0].Split('-')[1]);
        startPosition = arr[0].Split('-')[0].Trim();
    }

    HttpFileCollection SelectedFiles = context.Request.Files;

    try
    {

        HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;
        HttpPostedFile postedFile = files[0];

        string filename = postedFile.FileName;
        HttpPostedFile PostedFile = SelectedFiles[0];
        string strFileName = Request.Form[0];

        Stream sreader = postedFile.InputStream;
        long length = postedFile.InputStream.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        int bytetoread = sreader.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        byte[] buffer = bytes;

        if (startPosition.Equals("bytes 0") || String.IsNullOrEmpty(startPosition))
        {
            // If first chunk the get conditional path from DB by control id
            pathByControl = GetPathFromDBByControlId(controlId);
        }
        if (chunk != chunks)
        {
            //Returning conditionl path for remain chunk
            context.Response.Write("{\"PathByControl\":\"" + pathByControl + "\"}");
        }

        // Uploading file on FTP server
        UploadFileOnFTP(strFileName, rootPath + pathByControl + nodifiedFileName, buffer, chunk, chunks); 

        if (chunk == chunks)
        {
            //If all chunks are uploaded then insert detail in DB
            InsertFileDetailInDB(rootPath + pathByControl + nodifiedFileName, nodifiedFileName, PostedFile.FileName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Write("{\"Error\":\"" + ex.Message+"\"}");
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public string GetPathFromDBByControlId(String ControlId)
{
    return "";
}
public void UploadFileOnFTP(string _FileName, string _UploadPath, byte[] bufferToWrite, long chunk, long chunks)
{
    string ftphost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP_IP"].ToString();
    string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + ftphost + "/" + _UploadPath;
    string _FTPUser = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP_USER"]);
    string _FTPPass = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTP_PASS"]);

    try
    {
        System.Net.FtpWebRequest _FtpWebRequest = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpfullpath));
        // Provide the WebPermission Credintials
        _FtpWebRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass);
        // By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
        // after a command is executed.
        _FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        // set timeout for 20 seconds
        _FtpWebRequest.Timeout = -1;
        // Specify the command to be executed.
        _FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile;
        // Specify the data transfer type.
        _FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = true;           
        using (Stream _Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // System.IO.Stream _Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            _Stream.Write(bufferToWrite, 0, bufferToWrite.Length);
            // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
            _Stream.Close();
            _Stream.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
public void InsertFileDetailInDB(String Path, String ModifiedName, String OrigionalName)
{
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Code added in question.